# Elegantly apply a map to all items of a clist (LaTeX3)

Tags: latex3

I’m trying to apply (edit: *in place*) a simple map to map the list `1,2,3` to `2,3,4` by adding 1 to each item. However, I can’t find a more elegant way than defining a new list for that. Can this code be improved?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_clear_new:N \l_blenderpoint_clist % Will be used to contain the list to sort
\clist_set:Nx \l_blenderpoint_clist {1,2,3}
My ~ list ~ is ~
\l_blenderpoint_clist

\\

\clist_clear_new:N \l_blenderpoint_clist_two % Will be used to contain the list to sort
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_blenderpoint_clist {
  \clist_put_right:Nx \l_blenderpoint_clist_two {\int_eval:n{#1+1}}
}
\clist_set:Nx \l_blenderpoint_clist \l_blenderpoint_clist_two

My ~ list ~ is ~
\l_blenderpoint_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\foo\clist_map_inline:nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{1,2,3}{\inteval{#1+1},}

\end{document}
```

---

after the updated question, saving back to the list:

```
\documentclass{article}



\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N\l_blenderpoint_clist
\clist_set:Nn\l_blenderpoint_clist{1,2,3}
\clist_show:N\l_blenderpoint_clist
\cs_new:Npn\l_add:n#1{\int_eval:n{#1+1},}
\clist_set:Nx\l_blenderpoint_clist{\clist_map_function:NN\l_blenderpoint_clist\l_add:n}
\clist_show:N\l_blenderpoint_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
```

log:

```
The comma list \l_blenderpoint_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {1}
>  {2}
>  {3}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.8 \clist_show:N\l_blenderpoint_clist
                                      
? 
The comma list \l_blenderpoint_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {2}
>  {3}
>  {4}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.11 \clist_show:N\l_blenderpoint_clist
                                       
?
```

Comment: Thanks, but here you are not updating in place the list. I’ve clarified my question.

Comment: @tobiasBora you can save the new list back in the original csname, so that is a minor detail

Comment: Oh, I was expecting some sort of circular issues in that case

Comment: @tobiasBora updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Use a scratch clist.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l__tborachangeclist_temp_clist % temporary

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tbora_changeclist:Nn
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l__tborachangeclist_temp_clist
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nx \l__tborachangeclist_temp_clist { #2 }
   }
  \clist_set_eq:NN #1 \l__tborachangeclist_temp_clist
 }

%%% test

\clist_new:N \l_tbora_list_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_tbora_list_clist { 1, 2, 3 }

\tbora_changeclist:Nn \l_tbora_list_clist { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } }

\clist_show:N \l_tbora_list_clist

\tbora_changeclist:Nn \l_tbora_list_clist { -#1- }

\clist_show:N \l_tbora_list_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff

\stop
```

The console will show

```
The comma list \l_tbora_list_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1}
>  {2}
>  {3}.
<recently read> }

l.22 \clist_show:N \l_tbora_list_clist

?
The comma list \l_tbora_list_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {2}
>  {3}
>  {4}.
<recently read> }

l.26 \clist_show:N \l_tbora_list_clist

?
The comma list \l_tbora_list_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {-2-}
>  {-3-}
>  {-4-}.
<recently read> }
```

You might want to use sequences rather than clists: the former variable type is much more flexible.

```
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1, 2, 3 }
\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq

\seq_set_map_x:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } }
\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq

\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_seq { -#1- }
\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
```

would output

```
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {1}
>  {2}
>  {3}.
<recently read> }

l.6 \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq

?
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {2}
>  {3}
>  {4}.
<recently read> }

l.9 \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq

?
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {-2-}
>  {-3-}
>  {-4-}.
<recently read> }
```

Comment: Thanks! So this is quite close to my initial solution, except that you incorporate it in a function for easier re-use. So I guess there is no better option ^^ I’m curious to understand, why don’t LaTeX3 define inplace map operations? Seems like a rather frequent usecase.

Comment: @tobiasBora There is, but for sequences and not clists. I added the example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trick I've used a couple of times in similar situations.  We define a core function that applies a map to one clist and stores it in another, with the clist being passed in as an `n` type parameter.  So this has argument specifier `NnN` where the first `N` is the new clist, the `n` is the original clist, and the last `N` is the map function to be applied.  Then we define a variant of this with specifier `NVN` so that we can pass a clist *variable* as the second parameter.  Lastly, we define a wrapper around this which uses the *same* clist for both the first and second arguments.

In effect, we pass the same clist to the core function but once as pass-by-reference and once as pass-by-value.  This duplicates the clist and allows us to assign to it while also reading it.  From the programmers point of view then the duplication is all handled by the LaTeX3 expansion routines and so is hidden from view.

Note that this only works with types that can be passed-by-value, such as clists (which are secretly token lists), token lists, integers, and a few others.  I don't think it would work easily with a more complicated object like a prop or a seq (I'm sure you could get it to work, but it might be sensitive to how those are stored).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685230/86}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \apply_map_to_clist:NnN #1#2#3
{
  \clist_clear:N #1
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
  {
    \clist_put_right:Nx #1 {#3 {##1}}
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \apply_map_to_clist:NnN {NVN}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \apply_map_to_clist:NN #1#2
{
 \apply_map_to_clist:NVN #1#1#2
}

\clist_clear_new:N \l_blenderpoint_clist
\clist_set:Nx \l_blenderpoint_clist {1,2,3}
\clist_show:N \l_blenderpoint_clist

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \add_one:n #1 {\int_eval:n {#1+1}}
\apply_map_to_clist:NN \l_blenderpoint_clist \add_one:n
\clist_show:N \l_blenderpoint_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following on the terminal:

```
The comma list \l_blenderpoint_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {1}
>  {2}
>  {3}.
<recently read> }
 
l.21 \clist_show:N \l_blenderpoint_clist
                                      
The comma list \l_blenderpoint_clist contains the items (without outer
braces):
>  {2}
>  {3}
>  {4}.
<recently read> }
 
l.25 \clist_show:N \l_blenderpoint_clist
```

Note that in this implementation, the map function has to be expandable.  I'm sure that there are ways around this, say if the map function assigned some variable that then got stored in the clist.

Comment: Ahah nice trick, thanks. I’m curious to understand, why don’t LaTeX3 define inplace map operations? Coming from a functional background, it seems like a rather frequent usecase ^^